# Best way to parse JSON string without getting stuck with structure or class

Tags: c#, json

Could you help me to find out the best way to parse JSON string (coming as web service parameter).

using either JavaScriptSerializer or DataContractJsonSerializer based on deserialization is useless for me since the client does't accept to share with me common data structure (class).

Regards

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use JavaScriptSerializer? Are you using Silverlight?

Comment: Thanks Kim, No i don't use Silverlight, i can't use JavaScriptSerializer because in this case i have to shape a strongly typed data-structure (since i work under framework 3.5) (4.0 use dynamic object), and this cannot happend since the client refuse to fet stuck with classor structure.

Answer (score 7):

I've used [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) various times in the past - it lets you parse JSON into something a bit like an XML DOM, rather than requiring "real" types. Look at the ["LINQ to JSON" part of the documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/LINQtoJSON.html).

Comment: Thanks Jon i know it, is there anything else that not need a third party to be included.

Comment: It would have been nice to have the "no 3rd party libraries" requirement as part of the question to start with. I don't know of any other way of doing this without basically writing your own JSON parser.

Comment: I'am still waiting for further idea

Comment: @user852194: Well you shouldn't expect to get one from me... basically I've given you all the options I know of. To be honest, in this day and age the requirement of "no third party libraries" is a pretty unreasonable one.

Comment: Thanks Jon i'am writing my message above because this is the only place i find. i'am novice in this forum, jejejejejeje